# Different message on no arguments provided, Discord + Python

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a Commands list for my Discord bot, and have been prototyping the whole ordeal. This is what I've got, but the thing is even if the first two work, the last one (supposed to trigger when no arguments are provided) doesn't trigger at all.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)

async def test(ctx, *msg):
    msg = ctx.message.content.split(" ", 1)
    if msg[1] == "yes":
        await bot.say("This is a valid argument!")
        # do thing...
    else:
        await bot.say("Not a valid argument!")
    if len(msg) == 0:
        await bot.say("Try using an argument. For example: !test yes")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't overwrite `msg`, use the one that the command parser generates.  Test for the length of `args` first, then test for valid values.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def test(ctx, *args):
    if not args:
        await bot.say("Try using an argument. For example: !test yes")
    elif args[0] == "yes":
        await bot.say("This is a valid argument!")
    else:
        await bot.say("Not a valid argument!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a `list` as msg, as `msg[1]` uses a number as index.

Not sure about other types as I'm not too experienced in Python, but the length of a list is the number of items in it.

```
test = ["test"]
print(len(test))
```

Output: `1`

So, when you do `if len(msg) == 0`, you are checking if the message sent has 0 words in it, so empty. Try `if len(msg) == 1` instead.